# sum of multiples by 3 or 5 using ranges

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, functional-programming, c++20

This program calculates the sum of all integers in the range \$[1, 1000)\$ which are multiples of either 3 or 5 or both.

Inspired by [x86-64 Assembly - Sum of multiples of 3 or 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253680/x86-64-assembly-sum-of-multiples-of-3-or-5) the other day, and also drawing from some of what I learned through [Calculate the centroid of a collection of complex numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253721/calculate-the-centroid-of-a-collection-of-complex-numbers) I decided to try to tackle this using C++20 ranges.  By heavy use of `constexpr`, I had hoped to find a solution that would calculate everything at compile time, and indeed this does as you can see if you try it [online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x8zcK8).

This version is inspired by this talk [C++20 Ranges in Practice - Tristan Brindle - CppCon 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_E-VLyUnzc).

I'm interested in general improvements.

### euler1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

template <std::ranges::input_range R,
    typename Init = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
constexpr Init accumulate(R&& rng, Init init = Init{}) 
{
    return std::reduce(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng),
        std::move(init));
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto div3_or_5 = [](int i){ return i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0; };
    std::cout << accumulate(std::ranges::iota_view{1, 1000}
        | std::views::filter(div3_or_5)
        | std::views::common)
    << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That hat really does have your name on it.... `:_)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional `init` argement is never used, so we could omit that for this application, and use the two-argument form of `std::reduce()`.

That would solve the other issue neatly - failure to include `<utility>` before using `std::move()`.

Answer (score 4):

I see you already solved your own questions from before your latest edit. Just two very minor things that can be improved: you can omit repeating the type name `Init` in two places:

```
template <std::ranges::input_range R, typename Init = std::ranges::range_value_t<R>>
constexpr auto accumulate(R&& rng, Init init = {}) 
{
    return std::reduce(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng), std::move(init));
}
```

And you don't need to use `std::views::common` in `main()`.